# Unable to upload report to Katalon Analytics

Tags: automated-tests, katalon-studio

I had a problem when trying to upload report to Katalon Analytics. Did anyone using Katalon testing tool encountered the problem before? I followed the [Katalon website](https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/tutorials/upload-test-execution-reports-katalon-analytics/) to upload the document. But it failed.

[unable to upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTC06.png)

Comment: Is it possible for you to login in your account at https://analytics.katalon.com/login ???

Comment: Yes, JanZ. I am able to login to my account. I can see my project with the project ID that I have created in the Katalon analytics. Everything looks good to me. But I could not upload the testing report to Katalon analytics.

Comment: @user7581348 : Have you executed a test case or a test suite?

Comment: yes. I ran the test suite and test case. But no luck. Could not upload the testing report to Katalon analytics.

Comment: Which Katalon version are you using?

Comment: I did not get a chance to check the latest version which is 5.8.4. I was using 5.6. Let me know if you can. Thank you.